# Mysql - How to split text variable in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a `MySQL` variable as below.

```
DECLARE str TEXT DEFAULT '2014-01-02 13:00:00|2014-02-04 12:59:59@0@2014-02-04 13:00:00|2014-03-04 12:59:59@0@2014-03-04 13:00:00|2014-04-02 13:59:59@0@2014-04-02 14:00:00|2014-05-02 14:59:59@0@2014-05-02 15:00:00|2014-06-03 14:59:59';
```

I want to break this whole string first by using the separator `@0@` and from the results  break the string using separator `|`.

I have tried `MySQL` `split_str` function but I am not able to do it.
Its giving me the error `split_str does not exist`.
Please suggest some other way to do this.

Comment: Have you seen [`common_schema`](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html) and specifically [`split_token`](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/split_token.html)?

Comment: i am not aware of common_schema....let me check first.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have resolved my problem using below procedure.

I am able to solve it using temporary table and procedure. I am no more using mysql variable for this. We can call the procedure as below....

```
 CALL SplitString('2014-01-02 13:00:00|2014-02-04 12:59:59@0@2014-02-04 13:00:00|2014-03-04 12:59:59@0@2014-03-04 13:00:00|2014-04-02 13:59:59@0@2014-04-02 14:00:00|2014-05-02 14:59:59@0@2014-05-02 15:00:00|2014-06-03 14:59:59', '@0@', 'tblindex');
```

Here tblindex is temporary table i have used.

My procedure is below....

```
 DELIMITER $$

 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SplitString`$$

 CREATE PROCEDURE `SplitString`( IN input TEXT,IN delm VARCHAR(10),tblnm varchar(50))
 BEGIN
     DECLARE cur_position INT DEFAULT 1 ;
     DECLARE remainder TEXT;
     DECLARE cur_string VARCHAR(1000);
     DECLARE delm_length TINYINT UNSIGNED;
     set @sql_drop = concat("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ",tblnm); 
     prepare st_drop from @sql_drop;
     execute st_drop; 
     set @sql_create = concat("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ",tblnm," (value VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MEMORY;");
     prepare st_create from @sql_create;
     execute st_create; 
     SET remainder = input;
     SET delm_length = CHAR_LENGTH(delm);
     WHILE CHAR_LENGTH(remainder) > 0 AND cur_position > 0 
     DO
         SET cur_position = INSTR(remainder, delm);
         IF cur_position = 0 THEN
             SET cur_string = remainder;
         ELSE
             SET cur_string = LEFT(remainder, cur_position - 1);
         END IF;
         -- select cur_string;
         IF TRIM(cur_string) != '' THEN
             set @sql_insert = concat("INSERT INTO ",tblnm," VALUES ('",cur_string,"');");
             prepare st_insert from @sql_insert;
             execute st_insert; 
         END IF;
         SET remainder = SUBSTRING(remainder, cur_position + delm_length);
     END WHILE;

 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```